# ¿Cómo eliminar un objeto de un arreglo de objetos en JavaScript o jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Suponiendo que tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos:

```
    var travelers = [
         {
           "name":"ana",
           "lastname":"gomez"
         },
         {
           "name":"juan",
           "lastname":"gomez"
         },
         {
           "name":"luis",
           "lastname":"gomez"
         },
         {
           "name":"pedro",
           "lastname":"gomez"
         }
    ];
```

Quisiera saber si ¿hay alguna manera de eliminar un objeto del arreglo en **JavaScript** puro o **jQuery**?, ingresando la posición del objeto que se quiere eliminar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puedes usar [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice):

Sintáxis:

> array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])

Por ejemplo si quisieras borrar el tercer elemento de tu array:

```
travelers.splice(2, 1)
```

El array quedaría asi:

```
var travelers = [
     {
       "name":"ana",
       "lastname":"gomez"
     },
     {
       "name":"juan",
       "lastname":"gomez"
     },
     {
       "name":"pedro",
       "lastname":"gomez"
     }
];
```

Lo bueno de `splice` es que puedes obtener un sub-array que contiene lo que has eliminado, es decir, podrías guardarlo para después si quisieras:

```
var elementoEliminado = travelers.splice(2, 1);
```

La variable `elementoEliminado` contendría:

```
[
    {
        "name":"luis",
        "lastname":"gomez"
    }   
]
```

Por mi parte, lo he usado en algunas ocasiones como un tipo de relocalizador, por ejemplo, si quisieras pasar el primer objeto hacia el último como una suerte de rotación:

```
> var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
> array.push(array.splice(0, 1)[0])
> array
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
> array.push(array.splice(0, 1)[0])
> array
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Aunque estoy seguro de que existen mejores maneras.

---

Otra opción es usar el operador [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete), pero lo que hace esto en realidad es eliminar la **propiedad**:

Sintáxis:

> delete expresión

Ejemplo:

```
delete travelers[0];
```

Ahora, si quisieras acceder al primer elemento te retornaría `undefined`, pero el índice existe, a diferencia de `splice`:

```
travelers[0] // undefined
```

Answer (score 8):

Puede utilizar varios métodos para eliminar un elemento de la misma :

```
//1
travelers.shift(); // remover primer elemento
//2
travelers = travelers.slice(1); // remover primer elemento
//3
travelers.splice(0,1); // remover primer elemento
//4
travelers.pop(); // remover último elemento
```

si tu quieres remover el elemento de x posición, usa:

```
travelers.splice(x,1);
```

también puedes revisar esto: [JavaScript Array Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Hay varias formas de eliminar elementos en javascript.

### Array.prototype.splice

Para usar este metodo, se debe conocer el indice del elemento a eliminar.

```js
var arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5];

var indice = arreglo.indexOf(3); // obtenemos el indice
arreglo.splice(indice, 1); // 1 es la cantidad de elemento a eliminar

console.log( arreglo );
```

### Array.prototype.filter

Este método se introdujo en EcmaScript 5, utilizando filter

Versión para EcmaScript 5:

```js
var arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5];

arreglo = arreglo.filter(function(i) { return i !== 3 }); // filtramos

console.log( arreglo );
```

Versión para EcmaScript 2015:

```js
var arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5];

arreglo = arreglo.filter((i) => i !== 3); // filtramos

console.log( arreglo );
```

Comment: una pregunta se puede usar el filter en objetos ? por ejemplo en algo asi ...var tasks={ aaaa: {comer:'nada', cenar:'fruta'}, bbbb:{ comer:'algo', merendar:'ades'}}

Answer (score 2):

En Javascript existe el operador [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete), el cual elimina una propiedad de un objeto (y en particular, también puede borrar un elemento en un arreglo).

El problema es que si bien borra el elemento del arreglo, no altera los otros índices del mismo arreglo. Por ejemplo:

```
var arboles = ['peumo', 'fresno', 'roble', 'acacio', 'pino'];
delete arboles[3];
if (3 in arboles) {
    // esta rama del código no se ejecuta
}
```