# ¿Cómo eliminar un elemento de un array multidimensional?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net

Estoy tratando de eliminar un registro que se ha guardado en un arreglo el cual al momento de hacer `check` en la casilla se guarde su valor junto con otros valores para después enviarlo por **AJAX**. El caso es que para que se guardaran los registros duplicados, se me ocurrió que si ya estaba en la lista pues, simplemente lo borre al momento de volver a presionar la misma casilla y así no duplicar el registro.

<strike>Buscando en la web encontré una función, pero a la hora de realizar una prueba me marca error en el `indexof`, este es parte del código:</strike>

**Actualizacion:**
Encontré otra manera de hacerlo pero al momento de querer borrar, sí, me borra, pero borrar el primer registro en caso de tener más de dos checkbox, siempre me borraría el primero. ¿Cómo se hace para eliminar solamente el regisro que debe ser?

```js
var ra = new Array();
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
  var r_a = {};
  var Id_usuario = "andres";
  if (this.checked) {
    //RemoverElementoDeArray eliminaria el registro en caso de que ya se encontrara en el array para no duplicar registros
    if(RemoverElementoDeArray(ra,r_a)!=true){
      r_a.ID = $(this).attr("id");
      r_a.ACTIVO = "Y";
      r_a.ID_USUARIO = Id_usuario;
      ra.push(r_a);
      alert("se selecciono el registro"+$(this).attr("id"));
    }
  }
  else {
    //RemoverElementoDeArray eliminaria el registro en caso de que ya se encontrara en el array para no duplicar registros
    if(RemoverElementoDeArray(ra,r_a)!=true){
      r_a.ID = $(this).attr("id");
      r_a.ACTIVO = "N";
      r_a.ID_USUARIO = Id_usuario;
      ra.push(r_a);
      //alert(ra[0,0]);
      alert("se deselecciono el registro "+$(this).attr("id"));
    }
  };

});
function RemoverElementoDeArray(array, item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // This if statement depends on the format of your array
    if (array[i][0] == item[0] && array[i][1] == item[1]) {
      array.splice(array[i][0],array[i][1]);
      alert("SE ELIMINO EL REGISTRO");
      return true; // Found it
    }
  }
  return false; // Not found
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" class="Acheckbox" name="cbh_rol" value="Rol de Actualizar"  id="1"> Rol de Actualizar</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" class="Acheckbox" name="cbh_rol" value="Rol de Crear" checked id="2"> Rol de Crear</label>
```

Me basé en estas dos publicaciones:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943200/javascript-2d-array-indexof
- [¿Cómo eliminar un objeto de un arreglo de objetos en JavaScript o jQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1869/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-un-objeto-de-un-arreglo-de-objetos-en-javascript-o-jquery)

Comment: Posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1869/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-un-objeto-de-un-arreglo-de-objetos-en-javascript-o-jquery

Comment: gracias @DiegoSaravia si me sirvio para darme una idea , ahora modifique mi funcion combinandolo con otra que encontre por ahi para que dijera si existe o no el registro , sustituyendo el indexof , pero ahora solo me borra el primer registro en caso de que tenga mas de dos registros guardados

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo eliminar un objeto de un arreglo de objetos en JavaScript o jQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1869/c%c3%b3mo-eliminar-un-objeto-de-un-arreglo-de-objetos-en-javascript-o-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` no funciona en un *array* multidimensional. Para este caso, considere utilizar `findIndex`.

**Te dejo un ejmplo:**

```js
let eliminar = 10;
let items = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Flash',
    email: 'flash@demo.com'
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: 'Arrow',
    email: 'arrow@demo.com'
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Batman',
    email: 'batmain@demo.com'
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Robin',
    email: 'robin@demo.com'
  }
];

// Uso de findIndex:
let index = items.findIndex(item => item.id === eliminar);

console.log('lista de items: ', items);
console.log('id a eliminar: ', eliminar);
console.log('index a eliminar: ', index);

if(index > -1){
  items.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log('nueva lista de items: ', items);
```